# Will I lose search ranking if I switch cloud provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, seo, cloud

My website is hosted on AWS. My marketing pages are hosted on HubSpot. I have CNAME records that point to both hosts (www.mypage.com -> AWS and info.mypage.com -> HubSpot).

Q1: Is the search rankings for pages on info.mypage.com also giving credit to my main site?  That is, if my landing pages are doing well, does Google raise the ranking for my main site?

Q2: If I move my marketing stuff to AWS, will Google reset my search ranking? Or does it follow the new CNAME alias, thus giving my landing pages the same value in searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. Each page is ranked on its own merits. (But when it comes to spam and quality control having poor/low quality content on other pages on your site can hurt the overall site's rankings).
2. If your URLs do not change then this should be transparent to the search engines.